# Why has my graphics card disabled my on-board sound card?

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card, nvidia-geforce

Installed a Palit GeForce GT 240 (512mb GDDR3) graphics card last night and visually its working well, but it seems to have installed its own HD Audio device(s) in Device Manager, knocking out my normal on-board sound (motherboard sound connectors), resulting in Win 7 telling me I have no audio output device installed.

The manual talks about an internal SPDIF cable, but that only seems to apply to higher spec versions of the card and there's certainly no SPDIF connector on the card.

I'm happy to provide any tech specs people need to help on this one, just ask.

Not fussed about HD sound from the card, be happy with any sound at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!  Flash of inspiration made me reboot and check the BIOS settings.  The Onboard Audio has three options (Auto, Enabled and Disabled).  Was set to Auto, changed it to Enabled and all was detected.

I suspected Auto means "use it if you can't find another sound device plugged in"

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if your card has an HDMI port.

All you need to do is right click on the speaker icon next to the clock and click on "Playback Devices".

Next, Find the correct item (soundcard/speakers) and right click then choose "Set as default device".

[image]

Comment: The graphics card does have an HDMI connector, but I'm not using it, just vanilla VGA connector.  The playback devices show no audio devices installed. See screenshot at http://bit.ly/8yfGv0

Comment: Can you right click in the blank space and tick both "Show Disabled Devices" and "Show Disconnected Devices".. Does this make a change? And in Device Management, do you see any yellow triangles / are the audio cards still there?

Comment: Yes, both ticked, no difference.  Screen shot of device manager - http://bit.ly/8R5n1s

Comment: TBH, not sure if the devices listed are referring to the onboard sound or not.  All I know is sound worked prior to installation of the card and its drivers. Is it relevant that the mobo is nForce (nvidia) based and the card is an nVidia?  Could it be the drivers installed more than just pure gfx drivers?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the audio drivers?

Comment: Hmm...Driver CD contains file hdaudio_1.00.00.59_xp_vista_win7.exe

Annoyed that *graphics* drivers mess with *audio* setup.

Comment: Will Eddins - yes, via device manager's own "reinstall drivers" option. Not much difference made

Comment: The graphics card can output audio as well, since it supports HDMI, thus it needed to install audio drivers. It shouldn't have screwed up your existing audio, my Radeon 4890 had no such issues. You could try redownloading the drivers from nVidia or reinstalling from a Driver CD to see if it helps. If you can see your audio devices in device manager, and they're "Enabled", I'm not sure whats wrong here.

Comment: This certainly seems like a conflict to me and it could be related to both being Nvidia, however I have not used these personally and cannot give a 100% answer. Right now, if I was you, look on the Nvidia website and download updated drivers for both the onboard audio and your graphics card.

Comment: Done some digging - computer uses a motherboard with a Realtek High Definition chipset for sound. Gone to Windows Update Catalog to find the specific Win7 drivers for it.

Comment: Wil & Will - thanks for your sensible suggestions.  The answer was unrelated to these, but your attempts to help are appreciated.  I'll sprinkle some reputation dust accordingly...

Comment: Many thanks! Glad to know this solution for future - You are a Nice guy! +1 to answer and question!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your BIOS and make sure integrated audio is set to enabled. It usually doesn't cause issues when you install the graphics card, but for some reason on some it does. We just did a whole bunch of refurb computers for a client (20 computers) and all of them had an issue with the sound not working. After digging around on the computer BIOS seen this option, tried it and it works now.