# no sound with new graphics board

Tags: windows, audio, nvidia-geforce, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why has my graphics card disabled my on-board sound card?](https://superuser.com/questions/75352/why-has-my-graphics-card-disabled-my-on-board-sound-card)

I have no speaker in monitor. geforce gt440 sends it sound and onboard sound has disappeared.vista 32 bit .asus p5lp-le motherboard in a hp m8020n

Answer (score 0):

Right click the speakers icon, playback devices. Make sure it is set to speakers.

Comment: Only device listed is my monitor fhx2402l - it has no speakers!